# Is the frequency of consumption of Chocolate (Daily, weekly, Monthly) Ordinal or Scaled data?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

I've collected survey data and one of the questions asks:

"How often do you consume chocolate do you eat?"

-> None

-> Daily

-> Weekly

-> Monthly

I would just like to know whether these are ordinal or scaled in terms of SPSS.

Thank you, I apologize for the simplicity of the question.

Comment: The sequence daily, weekly, monthly, none looks ordered to me. I don't use SPSS and don't know its terminology, but I guess this isn't scaled.  If you administered using precisely the order you give (1) why did you do that? (2) I'll bet some recipients were confused (3) presumably you're expecting some averaging that you don't explain.(4) is this a translation from your own language because the wording seems odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, this is ordinal data. One possibility is to change it to a times/month variable so that none = 0, monthly = 1, weekly = 4 and daily = 30.  This would then be a count variable, which is discrete but ratio level.